# How can I support cancellation of a long running masstransit consumer task when the containing topshelf windows service is stopped

Tags: masstransit, topshelf

I'm using a topshelf windows service to host a masstransit message consumer. One of the consumer tasks can take up to 30 minutes, but is easily interrupted and restarted. When I manually stop the service I would like the consumer task to stop gracefully as soon as possible and to cause masstransit to return the message to the queue where it came from.

I now have this working with a `CancellationToken` that causes the long running task to throw a `TaskCanceledException`. In the bus configuration I use the retry configuration to wait until the process is finally killed, thus returning the message to the queue. Is there a better way to implement this? I now get an exception logged by mass transit, and my service doesn't stop as quickly as it should because it is waiting for the `Thread.Sleep`.

**In the long running consumer**

```
if (this.cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
  throw new TaskCanceledException("manual cancel");
}
```

**The retry code in the bus configuration**

```
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
{
  sbc.UseRetry(x =>
  {
    x.Intervals(this.busConfiguration.RetryIntervals);
    x.Ignore<Exception>(ex =>
    {
      if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
          this.loggingService.LogWarning("Worker stopped manually, messages in progress have been returned to the queue.");

          // Wait for process to end, this is not great because this causes mass transit to log an error
          Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
      }
      return false;
    });
  });
}
```

**When the service is stopped**

```
public virtual void Stop()
{
  this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
  this.busHandle.Stop();
}
```

Comment: I am having a similar problem.  Have you resolved this?

Comment: No, we are still using the code as posted. Please let me know if you find a more elegant solution.

Comment: How are you passing the cancellation token into the consumer?  When I Stop me bus the Cancellation Token on the context never gets set to Cancel

Comment: We are using topshelf for the windows service. In the configuration of topshelf we are calling `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` when the windows service is stopped. The cancellation tokens derived from this source have their `IsCancellationrequested` property set to true, and this triggers the exception (see code above). We need the exception because we need the mass transit message to return to the queue, not be treated as completed.

Comment: We are using MassTransit as well with Autofac.  Are you passing your cancellationTokenSource to MassTransit somewhere?  I think this is the piece I am missing.

Comment: We are using autofac as well. I register the cancellationtokensource with autofac as a single instance and it gets injected into the class that needs it.

Comment: Thanks.  Have not thought of that.  I will give it a try